# How can I force a line break before a long link?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can force a line-break before a link if it will keep the link from having to be wrapped on the new line.

In other words, let's say I'm displaying my inline link on a narrow device like a phone in portrait mode. I have a few words of text, then a longish link. If the link follows the initial words on the same line, the link will need to be wrapped to keep it from overflowing the container but if I can force a line-break **before** the link starts, it may (or may not) appear unwrapped on the newline. (If it still has to wrap on the new line, that's okay; I'm trying to handle the (many) cases where this approach will prevent any need to wrap the link.)

I haven't any idea how to accomplish this without writing programming code and even then I'm not entirely sure. Is it even possible? I'd far rather do it with CSS if it's possible.

It would seem to require the rendering engine to know what the width of the device is and to realize that the upcoming link won't fit without wrapping and then generate a line-break to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you want but there is differents css approachs:

1. `.container a::before {  content: "\A"; white-space: pre; }`
2. `.container a { display: inline-block }`
3. `.container a {white-space:nowrap;}`

**First solution always add a line break before a link, but with inline-block approach the line break is added only if needed**

Take a look below or on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ob6fxc1/):

```css
.linebreakbefore a::before { 
  content: "\A"; 
  white-space: pre; 
}
.inlineblock a { 
  display: inline-block;
}
.nowrap a { 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p class="linebreakbefore">
Collaboratively create economically sound niches before state of the art "outside the box" thinking. <a href="#">Enthusiastically generate fully researched</a> opportunities with dynamic growth strategies. Enthusiastically extend client-centered communities vis-a-vis optimal expertise. Uniquely grow business ideas through user friendly best.
</p>
<p class="inlineblock">
Collaboratively create economically sound niches before state of the art "outside the box" thinking. <a href="#">Enthusiastically generate fully researched</a> opportunities with dynamic growth strategies. Enthusiastically extend client-centered communities vis-a-vis optimal expertise. Uniquely grow business ideas through user friendly best.
</p>
<p class="nowrap">
Collaboratively create economically sound niches before state of the art "outside the box" thinking. <a href="#">Enthusiastically generate fully researched</a> opportunities with dynamic growth strategies. Enthusiastically extend client-centered communities vis-a-vis optimal expertise. Uniquely grow business ideas through user friendly best.
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, Zecka! That would appear to do exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I've actually implemented the inlineblock approach to my code and it works perfectly. Thanks again, Zecka!

Comment: Zecka, I've just discovered that your second technique works great on Firefox and Chrome in Windows and Android but it DOESN'T work in other Android browsers like Samsung Internet and Brave, Any idea how to make it work in all newer browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean the words appearing as the link should not be broken?

You can use "non-breaking spaces" ("HTML entities" written as `&nbsp;`) in your HTML code for this instead of regular spaces inside the link. That way the link itself will not be broken, as you can see in this example:

```html
<p>This is a longer sentence which among some other words contains a link <a href='#'>which&nbsp;consists&nbsp;of&nbsp;several&nbsp;words&nbsp;that&nbsp;should&nbsp;not&nbsp;be&nbsp;broken</a></p>
```

Comment: Not really. Eventually, if the screen is narrow enough and the link is wide enough, it will have to be broken/wrapped. I'm just trying to handle the cases where I can prevent wrapping by starting the long link at the beginning of a line. Zecka has offered some very promising solutions. I expect one of them will be ideal when I try them in a few hours.